# Python: Youtube DATA API refresh playlist in loop

Tags: python, loops, youtube, youtube-data-api

i have a problem with my YT Data API. i have a loop, which get one videoid from the playlist download this video and delete it from the playlist. 
But in the next Loop, the program want to download the same video, because the list which is executed again gives back, the video isnt deleted (but it is actually).
Is there any way to refresh the playlist, without make an OAuth every loop?

```
while True:
    request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part="contentDetails",
        maxResults=1,
        playlistId="myPlaylistksdjfksjdfks"
    )
    response = request.execute()
    test = response['items']
    test2 = test[0]
    idvid = test2['id']
    test3 = test2['contentDetails']
    videoid = test3['videoId']

    videourl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoid

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([videourl])

    delquest = youtube.playlistItems().delete(
            id=idvid
        )
    delquest.execute()
```

I hope someone can help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When posting code, paste it into the edit window, select it, and then click the `{}` widget to get it rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to allow time between deleting the entry and the next query.

Rather than asking for one at a time, ask for some higher number, and loop through all the resulting video IDs.  Then wait a while to give the system time to respond, and go again.

Also, to avoid hammering the server, whenever the playlistitems query returns zero entries, sleep for a good while before checking again (say, at least 60 seconds.)

Comment: And how i can repeat the oAuth without an user interaction? Should be an bot on my raspi later... i didnt find a way in python to do that

Comment: You'll have to figure that out anyway, because authentication will time out.  But sorry I don't know the answer.  Also I do find it odd that the results don't change without a new OAuth.  More likely, you need to give the delete time to happen, and I'll adjust my answer accordingly.